# Parsing A String Of A Particular Format

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm looking for a way to parse a string of this nature:

```
r-g-b g
```

or

```
g-g g g
```

or

```
b g-g
```

etc.

Basically, the letter determines what color circle to display and the `-` determines whether or not there is a link between the circles.

I'm kind of stuck as to how I could develop an efficient algorithm to do this using JS/jQuery/HTML. Any ideas?

Comment: what do you want to do with the parsed value

Comment: One easy way is to use [.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) like `'g-g g g'.split('')` will give an array like `["g", "-", "g", " ", "g", " ", "g"]` which can be processed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish, but here is my best guess:

```
var s = "r-g-b g";
var color = { 'r' : 'red', 'g' : 'green', 'b' : 'blue' };
s = s.split(''); //turn it into an array;

for (i=0; i < s.length; i++) {
    if (s[i]=='-') drawLink();
    else drawCircle(color[s[i]]); 
}

function drawCirlce(color) { 
   //your code for this 
}

function drawLink() { 
   //your code for this 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer I can think of is read the string one character at a time and do as instructed. The complication is that (I assume) you need to have drawn the next circle before being able to draw the link between them:

```
var s = 'b-g r r b';
link = '';
for ( var i = 0; i < s.length; i++ ) {
  // `s.charAt(i)` gets the character
  // you may want to do a some jQuery thing here if you have that
  switch(s.charAt(i)) {
    case 'b':
      prev = drawCircle('b');
      if(link!='') {
         drawLink(link,prev);
         link = '';
      }
      break;
    case 'r':
      prev = drawCircle('r');
      if(link!='') {
         drawLink(link,prev);
         link = '';
      }
      break;
    case '-':
      link = prev;
      break;
  }
}
```